# Why is my procedure for the evaluation of $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2})^n$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I need to find the following limit  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

For $u >0$ constant

**My try:**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=e^{\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} n\log\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}$$

Since as $n\to \infty$,   $\arctan (u n) \to \frac{\pi}{2} \implies $ $ \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\to 1 $  $\implies \log(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}) \to 0 $ and $n\log(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}) \to  \infty$ since the $\log$ is dwarfed by $n$  so the limit must be $e^{\infty}=\infty$. However the answer should be $e^{\frac{-1}{\pi u}}$

**Why is the previous calculation wrong? And how should I proceed ?**

Comment: We know nothing about the rate at which $ \log(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}) \to 0 $. Why would $n$ times this tend to $\infty$? What if $ \log(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}) =\frac 1 {n^{2}}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't see any $1/{n^2}$

Comment: @geetha290krm wait I think I am confusing it with $x logx \to 0,$ as $x\to 0$. How should I proceed then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\log(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \left(u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right) \to 0$ we can't conclude that

$$n\log\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right) \to  \infty$$

since this is an indeterminate form $\infty \cdot 0$.

We can proceed by standard limits as follows [using that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$$\arctan (u n)=\frac \pi 2 -\arctan \left(\frac1{u n}\right)$$

and then

$$n\log\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)=n\log\left(1-\frac1\pi \arctan \left(\frac1{u n}\right)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1\pi \arctan \left(\frac1{u n}\right)\right)}{\frac1\pi \arctan \left(\frac1{u n}\right)}\frac{\frac1\pi \arctan \left(\frac1{u n}\right)}{\frac1\pi \frac1{u n}}\frac1{\pi u} \to -1\cdot 1\cdot \frac1{\pi u}=-\frac1{\pi u}$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n= e^{-\frac1{\pi u}}$$

Comment: Is the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ log(1+x)}{x} =1$ valid with$ -x$ instead of $ x$?

Comment: @mathlover Good point! Let me check this issue.

Comment: @mathlover $-x \to 0$ s $x \to 0$ right?

Comment: yeah , but there is a sign change in the log, which makes it tricky

Comment: @mathlover Yes there is a mistake with a sign, I fix that!

Comment: You missed a sign in the last line. The limit is $-\frac 1 {\pi u}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes of course! Just fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u \,n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \implies \log(a_n)=n \log\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u \,n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Now Taylor series
$$\arctan (u \,n)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{n u}+\frac{1}{3 n^3
   u^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u \,n)+\frac{1}{2}=1-\frac{1}{\pi  n u}+\frac{1}{3 \pi  n^3
   u^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (u \,n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{\pi  n u}-\frac{1}{2 n^2 \pi ^2 u^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{\pi   u}-\frac{1}{2 n \pi ^2 u^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e^{-\frac{1}{\pi  u}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2 n \pi ^2 u^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what formula are you using to expand $\arctan(un)$?  I know the taylor series but that is for the argument going to $0$, while $\arctan(un)$ has an argument going to $\infty$

Comment: @mathlover.Don't you remember that $ \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac \pi 2$ ?